# STARTTLS command first - Monit on Nectar Cloud Instance

Tags: gmail, monit

I am testing Monit on a Nectar Cloud Instance, and am having trouble sending alerts when specific conditions are met. I am attempting to use gmail:

```
set mailserver smtp.gmail.com port 587 USERNAME "username" PASSWORD "password" using tlsv1
```

But when conditions are met, and emails are meant to sent, the log file shows:

```
Mail: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. #randomstring - gsmtp
```

I have looked around other threads, and followed simple fixes like making sure less secure apps are allowed, but cannot find any Monit specific fixes. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Did you figure anything out?